# Registering for notifications for iOS 10+ - notifications not received

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Before iOS 10 I was able to register for notifications and receive them. Now I receive none. Here is my code:

```
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
            if error == nil {

                if granted {
                    print("granted")

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                    }
                } else {
                    print("not granted")
                }
            } else {

            }
        }
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions

        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [UIUserNotificationType.badge, UIUserNotificationType.sound, UIUserNotificationType.alert], categories: nil)

        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }
```

By the way, sometimes `granted` is true, sometimes it's false. I don't receive notifications either way. The callbacks are the same as they were back when notifications worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems correct, but you can try something like this.

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .sound, .alert]) {[weak self] (granted, error) in

      guard error == nil else { return }

      if granted {

        // register for remote notifications
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        // set delegate
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

      }
 }
```

You will get notifications for ios 10 in the following method.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    completionHandler([.alert, .sound, .badge])
}
```

When you tap on a notification the following method will be called.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I have breakpoints in those methods and they never get hit.